# Activity returning null and producing NullPointerException even though I implemented it

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, parse-android-sdk

I have a class extending ParseQUeryAdapter so I can use the `notifyDataSetChanged` feature. The adapter class is called `mainAdapter`.
Here's my notifyDataSetCHanged method in the mainAdapter:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.getItems();
}
```

Here's my getItems() method in MainActivity:

```
public void getItems(){
    if(adapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The app crashes on loading. As you can see, I planted an `if` so that I can see if `adapter` was null. But it still crashes.
According to the debugger, it says in green after getting to the `if` line, "adapter:null". However, I have this in onCreate():

```
adapter = new mainAdapter(this);
```

And I declared it:

```
mainAdapter adapter
```

Is there a method I can put in that will solve my issue? Although I am implementing the class, why is it still null? I clearly stated that `adapter = new mainAdapter()`

Comment: The error comes from you instantiating an activity on your own which will not trigger the lifecycle callbacks so the adapter will be null. Use the proper activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference an existing activity then you have to pass the activity object to where you want to use it (or use getContext or getActivity when your in a class that has that available).

One of the things you can do is create a method that passes the MainActivity object into your ParseQUeryAdapter. Then when you are calling stuff in your adapter do: `activityObject.whatevermethodyouwantocallontheactiviy()` be shure to error check the activity object first though.

IE:

```
private MainActivity activity;
public void setup(MainActivity activity){ this.activity = activity;}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(activity != null){
        activity.getItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason notifyDataSetChanged is not getting called all of a sudden

Comment: That shouldn't have affected that at all. Did you call the setup method that's in the adapter from the main activity?

Comment: Nevermind that. fixed it. However getItems() is not getting called, but it is not crashing. Yay!

Comment: Apperantly "adapter" is null

Comment: If this code is actually in a different activity and another, different, activity is in the foreground its highly likely that the activity your trying to reference has been destroyed by the android system & as such the adapter instance has been made null. beyond that I can't help ya much.

Comment: Where do I call the setup method, I didn't call that anywhere. I just copy and pasted it

Comment: you have to call it from the MainActivity IE: adapter.setup(this);

Answer (score 2):

You should never instantiate your activity classes with `new`; they should be interacted with using `startActivity()` and related APIs.

An activity created with `new` won't be registered with the ActivityManager, won't show up on the screen, and *won't have any of it's lifecycle callbacks called*.

Since your `MainActivity` instance's `onCreate()` method has not been run, `adapter` has not been created.

In your case, it seems like you would want your ParseQueryAdaptor subclass to have a reference to your activity in some way, so that it can access the right one.

Comment: And how would I do that>

Comment: Using intents ::: Intent bullFrogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BullFrog_MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(bullFrogIntent, 1);

Comment: I'll try to do something. @Austi01101110 , what does the "1" represent?

Comment: You're asking how to do the "reference to your activity" thing, not "startActivity", right? Well, just make your activity create the ParseQueryAdapter subclass, and send in "this" into the constructor.

Comment: And is my error in my `notifyDataSetChanged` method, or by me declaring `adapter= new mainAdapter`?

Comment: @SnildDolkow ugh Im kinda new, it would be great if you give me an example by editing your answer

Comment: @AbAppletic from the docs:  If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits. also Snild is right: if you are just wanting to reference an existing activity that is already running don't do this.